How to select every nth animation keys?
I have an animation with keys in every frame. I need to select each 2 keys of the animation and remove them, then place the remaining keys so that they stand each frame again.


You can use a python script for that.
The following can be run from the script editor or using the toolshelf addon:
import bpy

def unselect_nth_keyframes(n, invert=False):
    selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects
    
    if not selected_objects:
        print("No selected objects with animation data.")
        return
    
    for obj in selected_objects:
        if not obj.animation_data:
            continue
        
        action = obj.animation_data.action
        if not action:
            continue
        
        for fcurve in action.fcurves:
            keyframe_points = fcurve.keyframe_points
            selected_keyframe_indices = [i for i, keyframe in enumerate(keyframe_points) if keyframe.select_control_point]
            
            for i in selected_keyframe_indices:
                if invert:
                    # Invert ON: unselect every nth key
                    if (i % n) == 0:
                        keyframe = keyframe_points[i]
                        keyframe.select_control_point = False
                        keyframe.select_left_handle = False
                        keyframe.select_right_handle = False
                else:
                    # Invert OFF: keey only every nth key selected
                    if (i % n) != 0:
                        keyframe = keyframe_points[i]
                        keyframe.select_control_point = False
                        keyframe.select_left_handle = False
                        keyframe.select_right_handle = False

# Example usage:
unselect_nth_keyframes(4, invert=False)

The last line calls the function, you can choose the nth keyframe base and the deselection action (see comments).
If you need this often, then use this script instead:
import bpy

class OBJECT_OT_unselect_nth_keyframes(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Unselect Every Nth Keyframe Operator"""
    bl_idname = "object.unselect_nth_keyframes"
    bl_label = "Unselect Nth Keyframes"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    n: bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="Frequency",
        default=2,
        min=1,
        description="Unselect every Nth keyframe"
    )
    
    invert: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Invert",
        default=True,
        description="Invert the unselection behavior"
    )
    
    def execute(self, context):
        # The original function
        def unselect_nth_keyframes(n, invert=False):
            selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects
            
            if not selected_objects:
                self.report({'INFO'}, "No selected objects with animation data.")
                return
            
            for obj in selected_objects:
                if not obj.animation_data:
                    continue
                
                action = obj.animation_data.action
                if not action:
                    continue
                
                for fcurve in action.fcurves:
                    keyframe_points = fcurve.keyframe_points
                    selected_keyframe_indices = [i for i, keyframe in enumerate(keyframe_points) if keyframe.select_control_point]
                    
                    for i in selected_keyframe_indices:
                        if invert:
                            # Invert ON: unselect every nth key
                            if (i % n) == 0:
                                keyframe = keyframe_points[i]
                                keyframe.select_control_point = False
                                keyframe.select_left_handle = False
                                keyframe.select_right_handle = False
                        else:
                            # Invert OFF: keep only every nth key selected
                            if (i % n) != 0:
                                keyframe = keyframe_points[i]
                                keyframe.select_control_point = False
                                keyframe.select_left_handle = False
                                keyframe.select_right_handle = False
        
        # Call the original function with the operator properties
        unselect_nth_keyframes(self.n, self.invert)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_unselect_nth_keyframes)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_unselect_nth_keyframes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

It creates an operator. You can run it in the script editor to register it, then search for the operator via the F3 operator search menu:

It will show options to change the frequency and deselection behavior, which you can change on the fly:

You can also add it to your Blender_User_Directory/scripts/startup directory, so to always have it available in the operator search without having to add it to your script editor and run it there first.
